# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is there an equivalent for iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8.1

`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` is only applicable to links against SDK 4, is there an equivalent for iOS8?

The app that I am working on has to exit and leave no trace for the user resume from, as the app provides a pay for service, and it requires that the next person using it cannot resume from where the previous user may have left.

I tried things like exit/abort and the latter but all appear to leave a trace to resume from...

Comment: Are you setting this in the info.plist/

Comment: the key is documented to work still AFAICS .. its use is discouraged but it should work

Comment: Its in the app plist (default) with all the other settings, there is another infoPlist.strings but not used this one. As for working with ios8 the documentation still indicates it only works for sdk 4, so any other ideas would be appreciated

Comment: The documentation states SDK 4.0 and later, suggesting it will still work with iOS 8

Answer (score 1):

In the info.plist for your app click "+" to add a new entry and select "Application does not run in background", for the value select "YES".

When an iOS app moved to the background it takes a snap shot and displays this in the multitasker, you will want to make sure that this doesn't occur when the app is terminated as you may be displaying sensitive information. If this is the case then look in to ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch to prevent that snapshot image from being taken.

Comment: Added what you suggested, but it still remains and on selecting starts the app. I need it not to present for the user to select.

Comment: Then something is amiss. I have tested that info plist entry and it is indeed working as expected. I think you need to be more clear. Do you mean the entry still exists in the multitasker window? If so that is correct behaviour. Are you saying you don't want it in the multitasker? If so, is this just because of the image it shows? If so you can add a black or blurred UIView over the screen just before ApplicationWillTerminate is called.

Comment: In the list of current tasks that have been put into the background  the app is still showing. If the user clicks on it, the app resumes - what I need is to remove it from the background task list. If the user clicks on the background app it comes to the fore which I have to try and prevent somehow.

Comment: The app is not resuming, it it restarting. The screen you show when you double click home is not necessarily apps that are running, but apps that were run but are now terminated. I'm assuming it will return to the default or first screen of the app when you press it?

Comment: Also, I've touched on it already but you didn't answer it... why do you need to remove it from that list? Is it because it's showing sensitive information?

Comment: It will be a paid for app streaming video, and the problem I have have with it is that it needs to fully exit, otherwise the next person using it will be able to run the movie. If the movie gets stopped mid stream via pause and then going into the background for whatever reason it needs to die totally.

Comment: If you have the info plist key "Application does not run in background" with a value of YES and you background the app whilst a video is playing what happens when you "resume" it. I'm guessing the video does not resume playing. The app is fully exiting if you have that key, it's shutting down. It can be relaunched from the multitask screen but it is a new instance. If you are seeing something contrary to this explain what and how you are determining this.